# Inverse of the element in the multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show that if $k\in \Bbb Z^*_n$ has an inverse with respect to the multiplication modulo, $n$, then $k,n$ are coprime.

Can anyone give me a hint how to use the fact that $k$ has an inverse with respect to the multiplication modulo $n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k$ and $n$ are coprime, iff (by the extended Euclidean algorithm) there exist integers $a$ and $b$, such that $ak + bn = 1$.

If $ak+bn = 1$, then $ak \equiv 1\pmod{n}$, meaning that $k$ has an inverse.

If $k$ has an inverse, then $ak\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for some integer $a$. Then $bn = ak-1$ for some integer $b$, or $ak+bn = 1$, which by the above implies that $k$ and $n$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there is an $s\in\Bbb Z$ such that $s\cdot k\equiv 1\bmod n$. This means there is some $t\in\Bbb Z$ with $sk+tn=1$. Now assume that $d$ divides both $k$ and $n$, can you say something about $d$ by any chance?